C# winform timer is not working while using EDSDK and windowsmedia playr at the same time
I am making a photobooth winform program and have an issue with the winform timer. The method works like this. When it enters the shooting state, It gets ready for 7 seconds and shoot a video for 7 seconds and when it repeats 3times, It goes to ready state for 15 seconds and shoots a photo for every 10 seconds and end. The problem occurs in this area. During the filming process, the example image is played on the side using Windows media player, and the timer freezes without ticking when you move on to the photography timer after all the filming is finished. The code is attached to the structure below.
private void Timer_Tick_Ready(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Flipbook.SelectedChallengeType!=0)
            {
                challengeCoverimage.Visible = true;
            }
            if (secondsRemaining > 1)
            {
                secondsRemaining--;
                readyTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                readyTimerInfoLabel.Visible = false;
                readyTimerLabel.Visible = false;
                motionInfoLabel.Visible = true;
                alertLabel.Visible = true;
                shootingTimerLabel.Visible = true;

                // 소리 재생
                soundPlayer.controls.play();
                Challengevideo1.Ctlcontrols.play();

                // 이미지 저장 활성화
                evfPictureBox.EnableImageSaving(true);

                // 새로운 타이머 설정
                //timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick_Ready;
                //timer.Tick += Timer_Tick_Shoot;

                readyGuideLabelImage.Visible = false;
                recordingGuideLabelImage.Visible = true;

                secondsRemaining = 7;
                shootingTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();
                readyTimer.Stop();
                videoTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        // video shooting time handler
        private void Timer_Tick_Shoot(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            challengeCoverimage.Visible = false;
            if (secondsRemaining > 1)
            {
                secondsRemaining--;
                shootingTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                evfPictureBox.EnableImageSaving(false);

                if (shootCounter == 3)
                {
                    shootCounter = 1;
                    secondsRemaining = 15;

                    shootIndexLabel.Text = shootCounter.ToString();
                    shootingTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();

                    challengeCoverimage.Visible = false;
                    Challengevideo1.Visible = false;
                    motionInfoLabel.Visible = false;
                    Challengevideo1.close();
                    recordingGuideLabelImage.Visible = false;
                    shootingTransitionImage.Visible = true;
                    coverGuideLabelImage.Visible = true;

                    videoTimer.Stop();
                    photoTimer.Start();
                    //timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick_Shoot;
                    //timer.Tick += Timer_Tick_Cover;
                }
                else
                {
                    //timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick_Shoot;
                    //timer.Tick += Timer_Tick_Ready;

                    videoTimer.Stop();
                    readyTimer.Start();
                    // 새로 영상 찍을 때마다 다시 초점 맞추기
                    _actionSource?.FireEvent(ActionEvent.Command.EVF_AF_ON, IntPtr.Zero);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    _actionSource?.FireEvent(ActionEvent.Command.EVF_AF_OFF, IntPtr.Zero);

                    alertLabel.Visible = false;
                    shootingTimerLabel.Visible = false;

                    readyTimerInfoLabel.Visible = true;
                    readyTimerLabel.Visible = true;
                    motionInfoLabel.Visible = false;

                    readyGuideLabelImage.Visible = true;
                    recordingGuideLabelImage.Visible = false;

                    secondsRemaining = 10;
                    readyTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();

                    evfPictureBox.SetSaveFolderPath(++shootCounter);
                    shootIndexLabel.Text = shootCounter.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        // Shooting photo tick handler
        private void Timer_Tick_Cover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("cover time tick");
            soundPlayer.URL = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Shooting_Sound.mp3");
            soundPlayer.controls.stop();
            if (secondsRemaining > 1)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("cover time " + secondsRemaining);
                if (secondsRemaining == 11)
                {
                    coverFitLineHorizontalImage1.Visible = true;
                    coverFitLineHorizontalImage2.Visible = true;
                    coverFitLineVerticalImage1.Visible = true;
                    coverFitLineVerticalImage2.Visible = true;
                    shootingTransitionImage.Visible = false;
                }

                secondsRemaining--; 
                shootingTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (shootCounter == 3)
                {
                    if (secondsRemaining == 0)
                    {
                        soundPlayer.controls.play();
                        _actionSource?.FireEvent(ActionEvent.Command.END_EVF, IntPtr.Zero);
                        photoTimer.Stop();
                        //타이머 객체 해제
                        readyTimer.Dispose();
                        videoTimer.Dispose();
                        photoTimer.Dispose();

                        // soundPlayer 메모리 관리
                        soundPlayer.close();
                        soundPlayer = null;

                        NextPageRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlayer.controls.play();
                        _actionSource?.FireEvent(ActionEvent.Command.TAKE_PICTURE, IntPtr.Zero);
                        secondsRemaining--;
                        shootingTimerLabel.Text = secondsRemaining.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    soundPlayer.controls.play();
                    _actionSource?.FireEvent(ActionEvent.Command.TAKE_PICTURE, IntPtr.Zero);
                    secondsRemaining = 10;
                    shootCounter++;
                    shootIndexLabel.Text = shootCounter.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

I tried to use dispose or other codes to release the memory but nothing actually worked. As adjusting the codes I figured out the sample video is the problem.
